# How to test Python function decorators?

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I'm trying to write unit tests to ensure correctness of various decorators I've written. Here's the start of the code I'm trying to write:

```
import unittest

from memoizer import Memoizer
from strategies.mru import MRU


@Memoizer(strategy=MRU(maxsize=10))
def fib(x):
  if x < 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)


class TestMemoizer(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_simple(self):
    self.assertEqual(fib(0), 1)
    self.assertEqual(fib(1), 1)
    self.assertEqual(fib(10), 89)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

While this works decently for the MRU strategy I have above, I plan to write additional strategies, in which case I'll need to decorate with the fib function in different ways. (Recall that because fib calls fib, setting fib2 = memoize(fib) does not memoize intermediate values so that will not work.) What is the correct way to test the other decorators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the tests in the standard library for examples:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/test/test_functools.py#l553

I usually add some instrumentation to the function being wrapped so that I can monitor the calls.

Instead of memoizing the test function at the module level, I create the memoized function *inside* the test so that a new one is created for each test and for each decorator variant.

Comment: Ah, right. Not sure why it didn't cross my mind not to use anything then fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing your MRU code when you're done.  Hopefully, you will post a link.

Comment: Sure! The code for my memoizer is here: https://github.com/Ceasar/memoizer
EDIT: I think my mru.py should actually be called lru.py

Answer (score 2):

What about the rather complicated

```
def mkfib(strategy):
    @Memoizer(strategy=strategy)
    def fib(x):
      if x < 2:
        return 1
      else:
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
    return fib
```

This way you could do

```
fib1 = mkfib(MRU(maxsize=10))
self.assertEqual(fib1(0), 1)
self.assertEqual(fib1(1), 1)

fib2 = mkfib(MRU(maxsize=10)) # produces another cache
self.assertEqual(fib2(0), 1)
self.assertEqual(fib2(1), 1)
```